# Script on AJAX Post response isn't executing just giving erroe unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to generate morris js chart in bootstrap dynamically using AJAX. But I couldn't figure out the issue and why I couldn't do it. Console.log saya "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {".

Here is the html code and the javascript where user will click on a button to load ajax content.

```js
$( "#report_form" ).submit(function( event ) {
 
                                  // Stop form from submitting normally
                                  event.preventDefault();
                                  alert('test');
                                  if($('#cb').is(':checked')){
                                      cb=true;
                                  }else{
                                      cb=false;
                                  }
                                  if($('#cheque').is(':checked')){
                                      cheque=true;
                                  }else{
                                      cheque=false;
                                  }
                                  if($('#tr').is(':checked')){
                                      tr=true;
                                  }else{
                                      tr=false;
                                  }
                                  if($('#especes').is(':checked')){
                                      especes=true;
                                  }else{
                                      especes=false;
                                  }
                                  
                                  var start_d=document.getElementById("start_date").value;
                                 var end_d=document.getElementById("end_date").value;
                                  
                                  $.post( "reporting/generate_graph", { 
                                     cb: cb,
                                     cheque: cheque,
                                     tr: tr,
                                     especes: especes,
                                     start_date: start_d,
                                     end_date: end_d
                                    })
                                  .done(function(chart) {
                                      $( "#chart" ).html(chart);
                                      console.log(chart);
//                                        $.globalEval( "draw_graph();" );
//                                      eval(chart);
                                  });
                                });
```

```html
<form id="report_form" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>reporting/generate_graph" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                          
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Time Period- from:</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <input name="date_start" id="start_date" type="date" name="" id="input" class="form-control" value="" required="required" title="" >
                                    </div>
                                    <label for="" class="col-sm-3 control-label">To:</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <input name="date_end" id="end_date" type="date" name="" id="input" class="form-control" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" required="required" title="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="" class="col-sm-3 control-label">CB:</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                                                <input name="cb" type="checkbox" value="cb" id="cb">
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <label for="" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Cheque:</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                                                <input name="cheque" type="checkbox" value="cheque" id="cheque">
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="" class="col-sm-3 control-label">TR:</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                                                <input name="tr" type="checkbox" value="tr" id="tr">
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <label for="" class="col-sm-3 control-label">ESPECES:</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                                                <input name="especes" type="checkbox" value="especes" id="especes">
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
                                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" >Genarate</button>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>


<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-2 col-lg-2"></div>
                        <center>
                          <!-- The Div for Charts -->
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8" id="chart">
                             
                            </div>
                        </center>
                        <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-2 col-lg-2"></div>
                         
                    </div>
```

And here is the html response that the above page will have

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body >
    <div id="chart_div"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

//function draw_graph() {
    alert('graph');
    Morris.Bar({

     element: 'chart_div',
     data: [
         <?php foreach ($graph_data as $bars) { ?>
             
         {y: 
             <?php echo $bars['date']; ?> , 
                <?php if($cb==true) { ?>
                    a: <?php echo $bars['cb']; ?>,
                <?php } ?>                                                
                <?php if($cheque==true) { ?>
                    b: <?php echo $bars['cheque']; ?>,
                <?php } ?>                                                
                <?php if($tr==true) { ?>
                    c: <?php echo $bars['tr']; ?>,
                <?php } ?>                                                
                <?php if($especes==true) { ?>
                    d: <?php echo $bars['especes']; ?>,
                <?php } ?>                                                
        }
        <?php
            } 
        ?>
     ],
     xkey: 'y',
     ykeys: ['a', 'b','c','d'],
     labels: ['CB', 'Cheque','TR','ESPECES'],
     resize:true
    });
//}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But Nothing happens. I want to generate the above graph. $graph_data is an array of a record set and it is fine. I have var_dump it and it gives a result array without any issue.

Comment: the closing `}` for your json has no `,` so on the second iteration your json becomes invalid. Dont build the json, build an array and then use `json_encode()`, it will not only will work; but will make your code much cleaner and readable

Comment: @Loz Cheroneツ
Thanks a lot. You save whole day of mine. Thanks a lot. It works now. :)

Comment: by the way there is just a one issue. the graph is generating now perfectly. But instead of check true false values of cb,cheque etc.. The graph contains all the bars even without selectiong cheque and other selections. can anyone help me with that ?

Comment: Process `$graph_data` within php first (if conditions ect), then output it.